# What is a good download manager with a timer feature?

Tags: download-manager, file-download

I live in South Africa where bandwidth is cheaper between midnight and 5am. Is there a good download manager that you can set to start downloading at a specific time? Preferably for use on Windows 7 64bit

Thanks!

Comment: What type of downloads?

Comment: Have you already tried looking for some?

Comment: @slhck yes, I spent more than an hour reading through the features of apps recommended under the `download-manager` tag on superuser and couldn't find a scheduling feature mentioned. Because of bad experiences specifically with download helpers in the past, I prefer to not install and try these type of programs without a trustworthy recommendation. How would you try looking for some?

Comment: I was just asking because often, users asking for recommendations haven't really tried looking yet, or already tried some tools – in that case, it would just be good to show what you've found and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions which ask for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly and attract subjective answers. For advice on how to ask a question which may require recommending software, see [this Meta Super User post](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) is an [open source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freedownload/) download manager with a powerful scheduler that will let you do exactly what you need.

You can create tasks to start all downloads at midnight every night and a 2nd task to stop them all at 5 am.

The forum also contains links to the newest beta builds from the developers.  They've been, in my experience, very stable.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. It apparently comes bundled with borderline malware Software Informer. Has anyone had issues like [this](http://download.cnet.com/Software-Informer/3000-2094_4-11096026.html#rateit)?

Comment: I've never seen Software Informer bundled in. Where did you see that?

Comment: I followed your sourceforge link and saw it reported in the community feedback. To verify I have now scanned the source code and found "Like FDM? Try Personal Informer!
The latest version of FDM comes with a free bonus: Personal Informer.", but it looks like it won't install the _bonus_ (from the same guys who make Software Informer) without your permission. So accepting your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many download managers both free and paid that will get this job done well.

I have tried and used many paid and free download managers but the best one that I have used is Internet Download Manager till now but it is not a free application.

The Internet Download Manger(IDM) comes with powerful scheduler and many more features that are immensely useful.

[Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/features.html)